# Naive Bays or Naive Bayes?

Tags: naive-bayes, definition

I have come across [a number of papers](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=naive+bayes&oq=naive+bayes&aqs=chrome..69i57.1630j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22naive+bays%22+) that write "naive Bays" instead of "naive Bayes". Are these different algorithms or just a popular typo?

Comment: If you see someone omit the "e" from Bayes' name you really have to wonder how familiar they are with Bayesian statistics (or how carefully they read their own work - and either option is a worrying sign). Anyone who has read more than a couple of books on statistics will have seen it spelled correctly many dozens of times, and if there was any doubt, one can easily search for it - the correct spelling does show up.

Comment: Your link takes me to a Google search for "naive Bays" but with results for "naive Bayes"....was this intended?

Comment: @Glen_b you might say that it is a sign that bae is naive

Answer (score 7):

It is just a common spelling error, [see this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Bayes).

Comment: I don't get it. It just takes you to a wikipedia page. What are you trying to show?

Comment: He's telling you to trust the way Wikipedia has it